# Form Navigation

Tags: forms, windows-phone-7

So, on iOS, you can allow users to navigation forms. (next & previous fields with arrows above the keyboard) Is there something similar to this on WP7? My app requires some amount of sequential order, and I'd like for the user not to have to tap every single field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in functionality which is equivalent to that in iOS.

You can, however, add the functionlaity to advance the focus to the next field when the user presses the enter key. And then submit the page when pressing enter on the last field.

There is a good encapsulation of this functionality inside a behaviour at http://pauliom.wordpress.com/2010/09/05/wp7-keyboard-helper-as-a-behavior/

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. However, from the phone number keyboard, there isn't any enter key... Any way around that?

Comment: @Hosemeyer If he inputscope you're using doesn't include an enter key then this solution won't work. Sorry :(

Comment: I figured. I wish they'd fix some of the input scopes... I have a few numbers only fields and would like an enter key but unfortunately the only one that will pop up a numeric keypad is the phonenumber scope.

Comment: how do you make it press the button? I've set a tab index, but it doesn't seem to press it.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour doesn't press buttons it only sets the focus. It would be easy enough to extend it to add the control you want it to always press, the code is available at the link. Otherwise you need to add a keypress event to the control in the tab index set that occurs before your button. If you visit the link there is an explanation of how it works that may help you too.